# Escaping curly braces in shell script

Tags: mysql, shell, escaping, curly-braces

I have a script to dump my databases, like this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LOG="mybackup/log/backup_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S).log"

# some other command

# backup mysql database
echo "Backing up database" > ~/$LOG
mysqldump -u myusername -pmypassword --ignore-table={db1.table1,db1.table2,db1.table3,db1.table4} db1 -r ~/mybackup/db/db1_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S).sql >> ~/$LOG 2>&1

# some other command
```

When I run the command in terminal, it successfully dump my database without ignored tables. But when I run the command through the script, it dump all tables in the database.

I have tried to escape the curly braces :

```
mysqldump -u myusername -pmypassword --ignore-table=\{db1.table1,db1.table2,db1.table3,db1.table4\} db1 -r ~/mybackup/db/db1_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S).sql
```

but it still dump all table.

My question is how to escape braces/brackets properly in shell script?

Comment: from memory, so I won't make in an official answer, it's easier to specify this option multiple times. The documentation says "To ignore multiple tables, use this option multiple times"

Comment: Stupid thing (again from memory) maybe escape the escape for the script as in 
`\\{` and `\\}`

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer why it DOES work on command line, but the documentation says to use the option multiple times:

[mysqldump --ignore-table documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table)

```
man mylsqdump
```

> **`--ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name`**
>
> Do not dump the given table, which must be specified using both the
>   database and table names. To ignore multiple tables, use this option
>   multiple times. This option also can be used to ignore views.

Comment: I read somewhere that I can use braces to ignore multiple table, and it work when I try it. Maybe I should stick to manual and use `--ignore-table` multiple times. thanks